# Firebase Test Lab: Is there a way to run test on production APK instead of uploading an APK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, firebase-test-lab

I have some apps hooked up to firebase and want to run some Test Lab test. Is it possible to run a test using an app that's already uploaded to google play or do I need to upload an apk when trying to run a test from console via TestLab -> Run your first Test -> Robotest?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when using Firebase Test Lab at the web console, you are required to provide an APK with every test run.

If you are opted into the prerelease reports on Google Play, you will get a free and automatic Robo test with each APK uploaded to an alpha or beta channel.